# ¿Por qué "vea" y no "veo"? Subjuntivo - presente

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo

> Cuando le vea mañana, le diré que la palabra "harto/a" es también usada en Mejico.

Mi pregunta es por que es *vea* no *veo*? Suena raro, si el *veo* se usa en este contexto sin embargo la frase es en el presente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cuando + presente* sirve para describir algo habitual.

*Cuando + subjuntivo* sirve para describir una posibilidad en el futuro.

En tu ejemplo, la única forma correcta es *Cuando le vea*.

Comment: Subjuntivo*, he intentado corregirlo, pero son menos de 6 caracteres y no deja.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizamos el Subjuntivo cuando el verbo de la oración subordinada expresa una acción no realizada. En este caso esta pendiente decir a alguien que "harto/a" se usa en mejico. Así que la forma correcta es "Cuando lo/le vea".

[*Dada la gran extensión en el uso de los hablantes cultos de ciertas zonas de España de la forma le cuando el referente es un hombre, se admite, únicamente para el masculino singular, el uso de le en función de complemento directo de persona: ¿Has visto a Jorge? Sí, le vi ayer en el parque*].

---

Otra opción en esta frase es usar el subjuntivo imperfecto con oraciones condicionales potenciales, aunque de esta manera se presenta el hecho como poco probable.

**Ejemplo:** *Si lo viera mañana, le diría que la palabra "harto/a" es también utilizada en Mejico.*

---

Una opción mas acorde es utilizar oraciones condicionales reales, que expresan hechos cuyo cumplimiento se ve probable en el pasado, en el presente o en el futuro.

**Ejemplo:** *Si lo veo mañana, le dire que la palabra "harto/a" es también utilizada en Mejico.*